# How to Remove Autodesk 360 entry from File Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, autocad

It works fine and I like that my work is synced to the cloud and available everywhere, but I hate that on my explorer windows there is a Autodesk 360 entry alongside my hardware, how do I remove that without deleting Autodesk 360? I need the service, but it's already accessible thru system tray so the entry on File Explorer is redundant.

**UPDATE**: Added screenshot

[image: File Explorer]

Comment: Where in File Explorer? In the context menu?

Comment: @Karan Hi, screenshot added please take a look..

Comment: The solution is probably here somewhere:  http://feedback.autodesk.com/cloudservices/topics/delete_autodesk_360_system_folder

Comment: @paradroid that solution need me to remove Autodesk 360, I just want to delete the 'shortcut'.

Comment: @Nur: Seems that you managed to figure out the key based on paradroid's guidance, but you should also mention it (either in a comment, separate answer or an edit to his answer) so that future readers don't have to go searching blindly.

Comment: @Karan Yes. Can you suggest me what to edit or add?

Comment: The exact key you deleted to get rid of that entry. Don't add it to your question itself though.

Comment: Create a folder with the same name (Autodesk 360) on the desktop if it doesn't already exist, rename it to anything else, and then try deleting this entry from the explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delete a registry key.

I do not have Autodesk 360 installed, so I cannot tell you exactly which it is, but you should be able to work it out by looking at the values in it.  Export the key as a backup before you delete it, in case you delete the wrong one.

1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. Now go to:

`KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace`

2. Under this key, you'll see a few keys having name in following format:

`{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

[image: regedit]

3. These keys represent those new items in My Computer window. If you select any key, you can see its description in right-side pane.
4. Select the desired key and delete it and it'll remove the associated item from My Computer window.
5. Following are some known Registry keys for My Sharing Folders, Web Folders and a few other items:

   My Sharing Folders - {FC9FB64A-1EB2-4CCF-AF5E-1A497A9B5C2D}

   Web Folders - {BDEADF00-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}

   Printers & Faxes - {2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}

   Network Connections - {7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

   Administrative Tools - {D20EA4E1-3957-11D2-A40B-0C5020524153}

   Fonts - {D20EA4E1-3957-11D2-A40B-0C5020524152}

   Scheduled Tasks - {D6277990-4C6A-11CF-8D87-00AA0060F5BF}

   Recycle Bin - {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}

So if you are seeing any of above mentioned items in My Computer window, select the key and delete it and it'll delete the item from My Computer window.

**Information from** http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-nokia-pc-suite-folder-web-folders-my-sharing-folders-or-other-unwanted-items-from-my-computer/

**Update**:

Based on information in a comment, the key you need is

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Explorer\MyComputer‌​\NameSpace{A7B36FF9‌​-3BB0-426B-A737-A997‌​B80466D5}

Comment: The exact key is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{A7B36FF9-3BB0-426B-A737-A997B80466D5}